# Setting the class of a dynamically created paper-button doesn't work

Tags: jquery, polymer

I have the following code that creates a paper-button dynamically.  It works well but I can't figure out how to set the class.

```
var button = document.createElement('paper-button');
button.raised = true;
Polymer.dom(button).textContent = 'dynamic';
Polymer.dom(button).innerHTML = "New Button Text";    
$(".notificationCollection").append(button);
```

This does not work:

```
Polymer.dom(button).class = "notificationBarButton";
```

I couldn't find anything in the documentation.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

additionaly, you can use

```
Polymer.dom(button).className = "notificationBarButton";
```

or even

```
Polymer.dom(button).classList.add("notificationBarButton");
```

classList has more functions `.remove` or `.toggle`.

documentation to classList: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the answer.

```
button.setAttribute("class", "notificationBarButton");
```